# Word for a sudden drop in ranking?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

My website ranking suddenly dropped from the top 10 to 1000.

My website ranking dropped ***abruptly.***

How do I use ***abruptly*** in the sentence above? 
I want to describe how the rank dropped suddenly from a high rank to a low rank.

Comment: It's **absolutely** okay and understandable. However, it won't talk about 'high to low' matter. It just talks about quick and suddenly without warning.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use **sharply**.

Comment: @Nico Agreed. *sharply* does include intensity or degree of dropping --here the rank from 10 to 1000 or whatsoever.

Comment: It fell off a cliff.

Comment: I think the user is looking for one word that includes both notion of "sharply" and " abruptly". "crashed down" maybe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want a word to express that the change in rank happened very quickly, was a surprise, and involved going down by a large amount. In this case, *abrupt* doesn't work by itself, because it doesn't carry a sense of downward or negative action. Your sample sentence means exactly what I think you're asking for and uses *abrupt* correctly, though.

If you want to change things up, there are individual verbs that mean what you're after. I would use *crash*. It conveys suddenness or rapid action as well as a severe degree of decline.

> My page's ranking *crashed* overnight.

See [definition 1C here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crash) and [definition 3 here](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/crash#crash_20).

Additional choices:

- Plummet
- Nosedive
- Plunge

Comment: I would actually say 'plummeted' or 'took a nosedive' would be better than 'crashed'. Since 'crash' is commonly used for things breaking in the online and tech world, it is less easily understood here (yes, the contexts are different and technically 'crash' can only have one meaning here, but it's harder to parse with that other meaning rattling around one's brain).

Comment: Alicja Z makes a good point about using “crash” in any tech context... It could be interpreted as a system failure of some kind. I vote for “plummeted”.

Answer (score -2):

Your two sentences as written are both good and convey the idea.

Are you dissatisfied with them or just asking for confirmation that they are good?